# How can I acces description of JFXTextField?

Tags: java, class, javafx, textfield, jfoenix

I need to see the description of the JFoenix component JFXTextField.
This should usually be possible with CTRL + clicking on "JFXTextField" somewhere in the code.
In this video it works, see 3:20
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MU0MCdk3i7s.

However when I do this, this is what I get:
[class description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DopzZ.png)

I don't know what's the cause of this so can anybody tell me how I get access to this description?
Thank you!!

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you using a build tool? And by "description" do you mean the _source file_?

Comment: description == javadoc? consult your IDE doc on how to attach sources or doc to a lib